# Unable to detect page navigation in Flutter Webview when using RocketChat

Tags: android, flutter, webview, rocket.chat

I'm loading a self-hosted rocket chat application from https://chat.domain.com in my flutter app using webview. So far, I'm able to load everything properly. Now, I need to detect when a user's profile has been visited and display a prompt.

e.g. When user1 clicks on user2 in the messages section, I should be able to display an alertbox in the flutter app.

In a web browser, the URL changes to https://chat.domain.com/direct/token when this action is performed. I'm trying to detect when this URL is opened to perform some action, but no luck so far.
Here's my code:

```
class _WebViewExampleState extends State<WebViewExample> {
  String loadUrl = 'https://chat.domain.com';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Webview App'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,        
      ),
      body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: Expanded(
              child: WebView(
                initialUrl: loadUrl,
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,                
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                  _controller.complete(webViewController);
                },
                navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
                  print('request url: ' + request.url);
                  //even the above print statement is not getting executed when user performs some action
                  if (request.url.startsWith('https://chat.domain.com/direct/')) {
                    String convId = request.url.replaceAll('https://chat.domain.com/direct/', '');
                   //alert here
                   //URL in the browser changes for this user action
                  } else if (request.url.startsWith('https://chat.domain.com/api/v1/method.call/sendMessage')) {
                   //the above url is called when a user sends a message, but this happens in the background. 
                   //URL in the browser remains the same for this user action.
                   //display some alert
                  }
                  print('allowing navigation to $request');
                  return NavigationDecision.navigate;
                },
                onPageStarted: (String url) {
                  print('Page started loading: $url');
                },
                onPageFinished: (String url) {
                  print('Page finished loading: $url');
                },
                gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using this plugin currently: webview_flutter: ^0.3.22+1.  I have already tried other webview plugins, but none of them are able to solve my problem.

I'm thinking of monitoring the outgoing URL calls from the app and trigger some actions based on that, but I don't know how to achieve that in flutter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hey, can you provide a gist or sample code on how you got rocket chat to work on webview

Comment: InAppWebView(
            initialUrl: <defaultUrlforRocketChat>,
            initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                debuggingEnabled: true,
                useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
                useShouldInterceptAjaxRequest: true,
                useOnDownloadStart: true,
                ),
            ),                  
        )